# Is it Possible to Change the Index of JSON after every iteration(Avoiding Duplication of Data )?

Tags: python, json, pandas, firebase, csv

What I m basically doing is Scraping data from Websites -> Saving to CSV -> Converting to JSON and Posting the JSON data to Firebase using `firebase-import` . This is the doc for firebase-import : https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-import.

Since, firebase doesnt allow creating unique keys via. firebase-import, so the data is completely dependent on the `IndexNumber` of the JSON data (you can see in the picture, no index number is same , so its considered as unique objects).

This is the Screenshot of Firebase Database and what I mean by Index.

[image]

This is same data (the structure) in Raw format :

```
    {
  "0": {
    "title": "Title 1",
    "description": "Description 1 here"
  },

  "1": {
    "title": "Title 2",
    "description": "Description 2 here"
  },
  "2": {
    "title": "Title 3",
    "description": "Description 3 here"
  }
}
```

I'm using python (pandas module) to convert the received CSV to JSON. This is the code :

```
csv_file = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv("file_without_dupes.csv", sep = ",", header = 0, index_col = False, encoding='utf-8-sig'))
json_file = csv_file.to_json( orient = "index",  date_format = "epoch",   double_precision = 10, date_unit = "ms", default_handler = None)
file = open("MiningJson.json", "w") 
file.write(json_file) 
file.close()
```

The Issue is everytime the Next Conversion happens, the index starts from 0 everytime and increments and **Overwrites all the previous indexes**. This is what happens when a new data is inserted:

```
        {
      "0": {
        "title": "Title 4
        "description": "Description 4 here"
      }
    }
{
      "1": {
        "title": "Title 5
        "description": "Description 5 here"
      }
    }
```

> Also, after every iteration , the json file is cleared completely.

Is it Possible to Avoid this , such as **Getting the Last Index of the JSON and saving it a txt file** and whenever a new Data is inserted, it should get the last index from the txt file and increment it from their. I think in that way, it will never overrrite the existing data and the Number System is Infinite , so it will be unique every time.

Please mention a better solution if you think of One. Thanks

Comment: There is no need to use  `pandas` to convert the `json` file. You need to convert the json file into a dictionary and then handle you indexing and dups as desired

Comment: Also, please skip the CSV conversion phase – just write JSON from your scraping script.

Comment: actually, Im using pandas for more than just shown in the question. thats the reason of using pandas

Comment: @EnriqueBet, how can i achieve this?

Comment: Could you just ignore the index by using `orient=records` instead of `orient=index` in the `to_json` call?

Comment: what's the schema of the table in firebase?

Comment: will it make a difference Changing to orient=records, because after every iteration , the json file is cleared completely. will it not start from 0 again ? @Serge Ballesta

Comment: It will indeed make a difference, because with `orient=records` the json will be a list of record dicts with no index at all. What I do not know (hence a comment and not an answer) is whether you can import it in your Firebase table.

Comment: without an index, i cannot import to firebase. That's the Issue Sir. Can You pls look at the question at the bottom. Can You make it possible pls @Serge Ballesta

Comment: your trying to re-create an incrementing primary key on your table, there is no need for you to do it, create your table with one and do inserts without the pandas index and you'll be fine. if you're worried about duplication you can create another table from the insert table that de-dupes based of your keys.